# Rolling mean across day of year

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, zoo

In my example below, I can calculate a centered 7-day rolling mean however, the first three days and the last three days are NA values. The rolling mean should take into account that day 365 is followed by day 1 and use that in the rolling mean calculation. How can I calculate a rolling 7-day mean so that there are no NA values?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

set.seed(321)

aa <- data.frame(
  doy = seq(1,365,1),
  value = round(rnorm(365,30,5))
)

bb <- aa %>%
  mutate(movingAVG = round(rollmean(value, k = 7, align = 'center', fill = NA)))

head(bb)
#>   doy value movingAVG
#> 1   1    39        NA
#> 2   2    26        NA
#> 3   3    29        NA
#> 4   4    29        31
#> 5   5    29        30
#> 6   6    31        31

tail(bb)
#>     doy value movingAVG
#> 360 360    24        30
#> 361 361    38        29
#> 362 362    30        29
#> 363 363    20        NA
#> 364 364    26        NA
#> 365 365    29        NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential option is to replicate your "aa" dataframe three times (e.g. 1-365 + 1-365 + 1-365), calculate your rolling mean for all values, then filter the middle "aa" dataframe (i.e. <s>1-365 +</s> 1-365 <s>+ 1-365</s>), e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

set.seed(321)

aa <- data.frame(
  doy = seq(1,365,1),
  value = round(rnorm(365,30,5))
)

bb <- aa %>%
  bind_rows(aa, .id = "index") %>%
  bind_rows(aa) %>%
  mutate(movingAVG = round(rollmean(value, k = 7, align = 'center', fill = NA))) %>%
  filter(index == 2) %>%
  select(-index)

head(bb)
#>   doy value movingAVG
#> 1   1    39        28
#> 2   2    26        30
#> 3   3    29        30
#> 4   4    29        31
#> 5   5    29        30
#> 6   6    31        31
tail(bb)
#>     doy value movingAVG
#> 360 360    24        30
#> 361 361    38        29
#> 362 362    30        29
#> 363 363    20        29
#> 364 364    26        30
#> 365 365    29        28
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Simply using the same data for preceding and subsequent year doesn't make much sense, does it? Alternatively you could expand *value* by the amount of missings generatyed in the rolling average and linearly extrapolate using this function,

```
> f <- \(x, n) {
+   na <- replicate(2, rep_len(NA, floor(n/2)), simplify=FALSE)
+   if (n %% 2 == 0) {
+     na[[1]] <- `length<-`(na[[1]], n/2 - 1L)
+   }
+   u <- unlist(c(na, list(x))[c(1, 3, 2)])
+   approx(u, xout=seq_along(u), rule=2)$y
+ }
```

calculate the rolling average and delete the `NA`s aftwerwards.

Here using `data.table`.

```
> n <- 7
> library(data.table)
> setDT(aa)[, mavg := approx(
+   round(na.omit(frollmean(f(value, n), n, align='c'))), 
+   xout=seq_len(nrow(aa)), rule=2)$y]
> aa
     doy value mavg
  1:   1    39   34
  2:   2    26   33
  3:   3    29   32
  4:   4    29   31
  5:   5    29   30
 ---               
361: 361    38   29
362: 362    30   29
363: 363    20   28
364: 364    26   29
365: 365    29   27
```

Of course, you could think of a model and predict the tails instead of linear extrapolation.